# what's the truth value of this statement

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

$$\forall x\in\mathbb R\quad \frac{x^2+2}{x^2-1}\in\mathbb R$$
I thought of making the equation equal to zero then solve it, but I don't think this would be right. I am having a difficulty finding the truth value of this statement, any help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As  first step, make sure you understand the meaning of the statement, in particular the meaning of $\forall$.

Comment: What happens if $x = 1$?

Comment: In plain English, the statement is saying "no matter what real number I plug into ${(x^2+2)/(x^2-1)}$, the result is always another real number". Do you think this is true? @user2661923 gives you a good hint...

Comment: The statement is malformed. We can't determine its truth value without a value for $\frac30$, which is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}(\frac{x^2+2}{x^2-1}\in\mathbb{R})$

$\implies\frac{1^2+2}{1^2-1}\in\mathbb{R}$

$\iff\frac{1+2}{1-1}\in\mathbb{R}$

$\iff\frac{3}{0}\in\mathbb{R}$

$\iff$ false